# Socket client and server java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java

The exception is at the the client side , I've tried flushing but in vain
This is at the client side

```
String usn6 = sc.next();
ps.println(usn6);
String po;
try
{
 while(true)
 {
   nf = br.readLine();
   if(Integer.parseInt(nf) == 1)
   {
     System.out.println("FIle not found");
     break;
   }
   else if(Integer.parseInt(nf) == 2)
   {    
       while(true)
       {
            po = br.readLine();
            if(Integer.parseInt(po) == 1)
            {          
              System.out.println(usn6 +" is deleted!");
              break;
            }
            else
            {
              System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
              break;

            }
           }
          }
         }
```

This is the Server Side

```
ps.println("Enter the file name: ");
ps.println("END");
while(true)
{
 filnm = br.readLine();
 System.out.println(filnm);
 File file4 = new File(filnm);
 System.out.println("getting hotter");
 if(!file4.exists())
 {
  System.out.println("getting hotter dude");
  ps.println("1");
  System.out.println("doesnt exist");
  break;
 }
 else
 { 
  ps.print("2");
  ps.flush();
  if(file4.delete())
  {     
   System.out.println("getting hotter daaa");
   ps.println("1");
  }
  else
  {              
   System.out.println("getting crazy daaa");
   ps.println("2");
    }
  }
  break;
 }
}
```

The exception occurs at if(Integer.parseInt(nf) == 1) the exception is a null exception

Comment: do you see the message "getting hotter dude" on the server?

Comment: Make sure that `nf` is a valid integer.

Comment: yes get the message "getting hotter dude"

Comment: nf is a string which i'm converting to an integer and comparing

Comment: Do you get back a valid value for nf?

Comment: Can you catch Integer.parseInt() method call exception in try{}catch{} block? See the value you are getting for that call.

Comment: i've tried catching but it shows                        java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at Client.main(Client.java:279)